# Issue with spotify API, getting back undefined response for genres, (after successful initial authorization request)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, spotify

The genreResponse, console.logs undefined, and I cannot figure out why...

Spotify Client Credentials Flow:
First you must request authorization, and then token is successfully received, and prints on to the console.
Then I take that token from the response (accessing it through data.access_token) and place it in the auth headers. Yes it is bearer token and that seems to be set correctly. I can't seem to find out why genreResponse comes back undefined.
The catch error doesn't log anything either.

```
      useEffect(() => {
        // Client Credentials Flow
        const config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET)
          },
          method: 'POST',
          data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
          url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
          
        };
        axios(config)
          .then(tokenResponse => {
            console.log(tokenResponse)
            setToken(tokenResponse.data.access_token)

            // second axios request to genre 
            const config = {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.data.access_token
              },
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/categories?locale=sv_US'
            }
            axios(config)
          })
          .then(genreResponse => {
            console.log(genreResponse)
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))

      }, [])
```

Comment: Have you tried to do these queries using postman or another tool? Just to be sure your URL and tokens are working

Comment: I just tried postman, but I'm not really sure how to implement this part.......  'Basic ' + btoa(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET)

Comment: ok I figured out how to make the second request on postman and it successfully response with the category data! but why won't it work in the app...?

Answer (score 0):

syntax of the .then .....
.then(genreResponse => { console.log(genreResponse)})
need to be next to axios(config)